# Can I migrate a CANoe project to a different version?

Tags: canoe

In my team we're working with CANoe 16, and we want to increase our number of benchs for testing, but in my company there is only currently available hardware with license of CANoe 10. Is it possible to transfer the project to CANoe 10 without having to make it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the configuration with CANoe 16, then go to the *File* ribbon, select *Save As* and as *File-Type*, chose *Configuration 10.0*.

That should do it, unless you are using some features, which have been introduced between CANoe version 10 and 16, of course.